# Proving a product of two functions is integrable over [0,1] when one of them isn't

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be a function defined on [0, 1] that is integrable over [0, 1], differentiable at x = 0, with f(0) = 0. Define the piecewise function g(x) to be $x^{-3/2} f(x)$ if $0 < x \leq 1$ and 0 if $x = 0$. Prove $g$ is integrable over [0, 1].

The fact that the exponent on $x$ is less than -1 is tripping me up here. I know that in general, $x^{\alpha}$ is integrable over (0, 1] only when $\alpha > -1$, so if I had an exponent in that range, I would have a product of integrable functions. But as it is the integral diverges. I can't apply Holder's inequality either, since clearly $x^{-3/2}$ is not essentially bounded. Am I missing something, or might the problem have a typo in the exponent?

Comment: A hint: use differentiability of $f$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Hmmm. So this implies f is continuous on [0, 1], specifically is approaching 0 as x approaches 0, yes? So do I have some general result that I'm forgetting when one of the functions in a product is continuous?

Comment: Differentiability at $0$ implies continuity at $0$, not necessarily on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I think that Daniel Fischer gave in his comment a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here since it's too long for a comment. This is only a rough outline of an approach, you have to fill in the details yourself.

I asssume you talk about Riemann integrability here. That means $f$ is bounded and by the [Lebesgue criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability) it is continous almost everywhere. Now use the fact's that $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is differentiable at $0$ to show that the function

$$ h(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{x} $$
is integrable. Hint: It is bounded on $[0,1]$ since it is continous at $0$. And clearly it is continous almost everywhere since $f$ is. Now use Lebesgue's criteria again.

But now $g(x)=x^{-1/2}h(x)$, can you carry on from here?

Comment: Actually, the problem isn't clear if it means Riemann or Lebesgue integrable. It just says "integrable," which could mean Lebesgue, in which case your answer wouldn't work if $f$ is unbounded.

Comment: Indeed, I leave it here anyway. Maybe someone else can give an explanation for the Lebesgue integrable case.

Comment: @BMac Pick $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\lvert f(x) - f(0)\rvert \leqslant (1 + \lvert f'(0)\rvert)\cdot x$ for $0 \leqslant \varepsilon$. On $[\varepsilon, 1]$, the factor $x^{-3/2}$ is bounded.

Comment: So that whole chain $|f(x) - f(0)| \leq (1 + |f'(0)|) \cdot x$ should end with less than $\epsilon$? Or where does $\epsilon$ come in there?

Comment: @MaikPickl There's no way this can work in the realm of the Riemann integral. $f(x) = x$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @zhw. How is that a counterexample?

Comment: $x^{-3/2}\cdot x$ is not bounded.

Comment: @zhw. I See your point.  One could argue that its integrable as an improper integral but that would also be missing the point. However the argument works together with Daniel Fischer‘s comment. Thats why I leave it like it is.